# Fitting a chart in half a page with css and html

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following `css` rules to split my screen into two:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

#col-1 {
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 122);
    flex: 1;
}

#col-2 {
    background-color: rgb(219, 176, 95);
    flex: 1;
}
```

I would like to show some text on the left and its corresponding diagram on the right, so I have written the following:

```
<section class="container">

    <div id="col-1">
        <h2>Gesunde Ernährung fängt beim Einkauf an</h2>
        <p>Schon beim Einkaufen können Sie viel für eine gesunde Ernährung tun – angefangen bei den Mengen...</p>
    </div>

    <div id="col-2">
        <h2>Graph view</h2>
        <p>Diagram Explanation</p>
        <div style="height:100; width:100; border: 1px solid red;"><app-pie style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"></app-pie></div>
    </div>

</section>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My `.ts` component class does not contain any code yet. These files are part of my Angular app.

The height and width adjustments do not make any difference at all. The diagram just appears at its original size:

[image]

How can I keep the `flex` property and also adjust the size of the graphic, so the two component look proportional next to each other? Is this possible?

Comment: it depends on which chart library you are using. some have fixes width/height for their charts. most of them also describe how to get them "responsive".

Comment: I have coded the charts using `TypeScript` and `D3` but I think it should be possible to adjust the dimensions using `css` rules...

Comment: its hard to tell on only a screeshot, but i think the chart will have something like `style="width: 800px"` or something like this. right?

Comment: maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415162/how-to-make-a-d3-pie-chart-responsive

Comment: @TheWuif It did, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your `<div id="col-1">`-column lacks any (fixed, relative) width information to "resist" the chart's horizontal growth.
Because, so far, just the graph's parent flex item does have an inherent width information (coming from the graph).
Try giving your left column flex item: `flex: 1 0 50%`.